# Blackjack minimax algorithm

Tags: java, python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am implementing a blackjack game with minimax tree which calculates the probabilities and play automatically depend on this probabilities.

Assume that, we play with 1 deck and the first game dealer takes : '**5**' and player takes '**5 7**' so the total score is 12 for player.

In this case, first I am trying to check all possible probabilities for player's **stand** decision.

If player **stands** :

My remain cards in deck like this : 
Structure of deck(K,V) K : card number, V: count of card

```
{1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 4, 7: 3, 8: 4, 9: 4, 10: 16}
```

Now, dealer should pass the number 17. Some examples can be like this :

```
5(base card) + 1(11) + 1 = 17  (possibility of this hand : 4/49 * 3/48)
5(base card) + 1(11) + 2 = 18  (possibility of this hand : 4/49 * 4/48)
......
5 (base card) + 10 + 1 + 1 = 17 (possibility of this hand : 16/49 * 4/48 * 3/48)
```

My question is, how can I calculate all this possibilities and calculate the final possibility of if player decision is standing. I cannot figure out how can I coded these combination of numbers.

**EDIT :**

I found out this code which calculate the possible combinations. It is similar what I look like. I need to change this for my problem, I hope I can do it.

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([3,9,8,4,5,7,10],15)

    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

Answer (score 0):

This game is not really a situation for minimax.

In minimax, two players make moves which are determined from a known position, and take into account the move of the other player in determining their best moves.

Since this example has two players, the Player (who does not actually move in the sense that he changes the state of the board except to decide whether to stand or not) and the Dealer (who only makes moves randomly), in an unknown board state with random options, minimax specifically cannot be used.

In this case, an algorithm that would work fairly well would be to start with the 5 and the added 7:

```
base = 5
cards = [7]
```

Using the following formula:

```
if sum(cards) + base < 16:
  hit()
else:
  if evalStand() > minStandChance:
    hit()
```

it is not necessary to calculate the card tree while true, since the player needs to get another card anyway.

After that, getting a probability of standing after that:

```
def evalStand():
  hand = base + sum(cards)
  sums = []
  for cardValue, count in cards.items():
    for i in range(count):
      sums.append(cardValue + hand)
  return len([i for i in sums if i <= 21])/float(len(sums))
```

Simply filtering out the ratio of possible hands that will still get the player <= 21. A commonly used strategy in this game is to creep up on 21. This emulates it. If the probability of standing after the next round is less than, say, 0.5, the player can stop getting cards.

Again, this situation is not good for minimax, but this should be a good alternate solution.

**Edit:**

As @NickLarsen has pointed out, `minStandChance` represents a heuristic. There is not a variable that is 100% accurate, but can be adjusted according to how much risk you want the AI to play with. (closer to 0 is risky, closer to 1 is conservative).

Comment: You are correct that minimax is not applicable because of the stochastic nature of the game, however there is a variant called expectimax which was developed specifically for this case.  Your solution has 2 constants (16 and minStandChance) which model "rules of thumb" rather than correctly modeling the actual state of the game.

Comment: @NickLarsen When you say that expectimax should be used, are you meaning that the average event is the chance of being in the 17-21 sum window and that the player choice is staying or not? I am not of the opinion that expectimax models the situation more accurately than what I have already, since it is not meaningful to calculate more than 1 turn out since the player has no influence over the sum of the cards. The strict mechanical playing of this game precludes using decision making strategies beyond whether it is beneficial to continue on or not, based on simple rules of the game.

Comment: Events represent state changes; in this case cards being dealt which there can be many in a single game even between 2 players.  Rules of thumb are heuristics that are correct _most_ of the time, not necessarily _all_ of the time.  Black jack is sufficient complex that I would expect hit on 16 or less to be incorrect in at least 1 situation, and it's almost a certainty that you won't find a value for minStandChance that is always 100% correct.  If there is one, you should add it to your solution.

Comment: @NickLarsen I understand now. 16 is a rule (as far as I have played and understand it), but `minStandChance` is a heuristic and should be explained. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I have updated my answer.